# Cookies not being stored with Fetch

Tags: express, cookies, fetch, jwt, redux

I have read every other topic I could find on this and none of the solutions worked. I am using React + Redux + Express and attempting to store a JWT in a cookie as per:

https://auth0.com/blog/2015/09/28/5-steps-to-add-modern-authentication-to-legacy-apps-using-jwts/

In my Redux action I am sending the following request:

```
export function getCookie(token) {
  const config = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ token })
  };
  return fetch('http://127.0.0.1:4000/authorize-cookie', config)
   .then((res) => {
     return res.json();
   })
   .then((resJson) => {
     return resJson;
   })
   .catch(err => console.log('Error: ', err));
}
```

And on the server I am responding with...

```
app.post('/authorize-cookie', authenticate, (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('id_token', req.body.token, {
    maxAge: 360000
  });
  res.status(200).send({ message: 'Cookie set!' });
});
```

...where authenticate is a function that verifies the token.

Everything seems fine with my response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: id_token=xxx.xxx.xxx; Max-Age=360; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 12 Jan 2016 01:24:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 25
ETag: W/"19-UA3htFr0PWczMQBN6T4NpA"
Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2016 01:18:03 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

But when I check the sources tab there's no cookie to be found. I've read about turning off httpOnly and secure and problems with using localhost. I've also tried in every major browser and no luck.

What's going on here?

Comment: Your cookie has `Max-Age=360` (that means 6 minutes). Maybe it expires so fast?

Comment: I've already experimented changing that to hours and days but still no luck.

Comment: As I see, you are going to `http://127.0.0.1:4000`. Is it actually the same domain, where your web page is opened? You can't save cookies during cross-origin requests.

Comment: Yes it's the same domain. I even set it up to allow cross-origin requests at one point to make sure that wasn't my problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You encountered an interesting case. The thing is that behavior of `fetch` function is different rather than `XMLHttpRequest`. To work with cookies in `fetch` you should explicitly provide `credentials` option.

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:4000/authorize-cookie', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({token: token}),
    credentials: 'same-origin', // <- this is mandatory to deal with cookies
})
```

According to [the article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch)

> *Credentials*: The request credentials you want to use for the request: omit, same-origin, or include. To automatically send cookies for the current domain, this option must be provided.